# How to query the database by clicking a link in a jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

hi i want to add a news section to my site.
so that the news list is shown in newslist.jsp and when the user clicks on news another page is opended with the link of for example shownews.jsp?id=1 and for every news eech id is diffrent.

would you please someone told me how to do that?
i just want teh logic behind it.i know how to write jsp and servlet  and how to coonect to dadatabse,but i dont know how to write the code so that when the user clicks on the links the user forward to the appropriate page with the proper ID

Comment: write code in your servlet that does so. preferrably, add some jpa or hibernate into the mix

Comment: You have several options `JDBC`, `Hibernate`, `JPA`,  `EclipseLink` ... It just needs a little configuration and writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag in your jsp page with attribute `target="_blank"`
for example:

```
<a href="your jsp page link" target="_blank">News Name</a>
```